# How to extract a subset of dataframe based on the last occurence of a string in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe lik below

| ID | name | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 2 |
| 1 | Danny | 5 |
| 1 | Sta | 2 |
| 1 | elle | 4 |
| 1 | Sta | 2 |
| 1 | jake | 9 |
| 1 | Andy | 11 |
| 1 | Adam | 22 |
| 1 | blah | 44 |
| 1 | blahblah | 66 |

I want to extract the records till the last occurrence of Sta.
like this below

| ID | name | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 2 |
| 1 | Danny | 5 |
| 1 | Sta | 2 |
| 1 | elle | 4 |
| 1 | Sta | 2 |

I am not sure how I can do that. Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would find `Sta`'s last occurrence and use it as the slicing parameter. There's an interesting function I didn't know that I found out working out this answer, `last_valid_index()` might be really helpful here.

```
filtered = df.loc[:df[df['name']=='Sta'].last_valid_index(),:]
```

Comment: nice ... since OP is only interested in the last occurence

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy check my edit, did you know about `last_valid_index()`?

Comment: Excellent and neat solution, didn't knew about `last_valid_index()` until now.

Answer (score 1):

```py
 first, *_, last = df.index[df.name.eq('Sta')]
df.loc[first:last]

   ID   name  number
0   1    Sta       2
1   1  Danny       5
2   1    Sta       2
3   1   elle       4
4   1    Sta       2
```

Get the first and last labels for `Sta` and index `df`

Comment: Is this scalable if `Sta` shows more than 10 times? Also OP doesn't specify it begins with the first appearance of `Sta`

Comment: it should, since OP is interested in only first, and last. Did it fail when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

```
staRows = df.loc[df.name == "Sta", :]
lastStA = staRows.tail()
lastStaLoc = df.index[lastSta]
final = df.loc[0:lastStaLoc]

altFinal = df.loc[0:df.index[df.loc[df.name == "Sta", :].tail()]]
```

staRows is every row where name is Sta

lastSta is the last row in staRows

lastStaLoc is the location of lastSta

final should be rows up to lastStaLoc

altFinal is the one line solution if you want to be fancy.
This is all untested so you may have to debug a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `groupby` with `transform` `idxmax`

```
df[df.index<=df['name'].eq('Sta').iloc[::-1].groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax')]
   ID   name  number
0   1    Sta       2
1   1  Danny       5
2   1    Sta       2
3   1   elle       4
4   1    Sta       2
```